# Calculate sum based on distinct values in other column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-analysis

I have a table where I want to sum based on distinct values in id column.

Main Table

[image: Main Table]

Pipe separated main file

```
Id|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|Dim1|Dim2|Values 
r1||||1.2||||sc1|c1|1.2
r4||||||0.98||sc1|c1|0.98
r5|||0.89|||||sc1|c1|0.89
r1||||1.2||||sc2|c1|1.2
r2|||||0.98|||sc2|c1|0.98
r3||||1.22||||sc2|c1|1.22
r4|||||0.98|||sc2|c1|0.98
```

Output

[image: Result]

Pipe separated result

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|Dim2
0|0|0.89|2.42|1.96|0.98|c1
```

For columns col1 -col7, I want to do this:
select  sum(col1),sum(col2),sum(col3),sum(col4)...sum(col7)
group by dim2 based on distinct values in id.

I could use row_number()over(partition by id) and use the row_number=1, but I can't use subquery. I am looking to do this in just one query.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two different database products.

Comment: Please add the sample data and output in text format

Comment: "I want to do a sum group by dim2 for distinct values in id column."  I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Thanks @AkhileshMishra I have added the output in text format. Also thanks for the answer but i wanted to do it without sub query.

Comment: You can not do that in a single query. You have to do that either with `subquery` or `common table expression`.